# Highlight multiple words when hovering over a single word or phrase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am creating an interactive website dealing with the translation of ancient Tibetan scriptures. I would like for **both** the English and Tibetan equivalents be highlighted whenever a user hovers over either the English or Tibetan Script.

So far, I have been using Tooltips (a wordpress plugin) to generate a dialog box which appears onhover. [My Site for Reference...](http://illuminationofthetruethought.com/the-offering-of-praise-and-a-pledge-to-compose-the-work/)
I do not care for the dotted-underline that is present when using this method, nor for the dialog box. I feel that the user experience would be much cleaner if I could implement another method.

Comment: Try using the `title=""` attribute on elements. Otherwise, this question is really too broad.

Comment: will do. Sorry for the lack of specificity. I am new to stackoverflow. roger that on the title attribute suggestion. I'll play with that for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I smashed a little Fiddle together to tackle your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6BH27/

You have to add a `span` around every word you want to connect and put the word in the other language as the `title` attribute of it. The rest will be managed by Javascript.

JS Code:

```
$('span[title]').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
        $('span:contains("'+$(this).attr('title')+'")').addClass('highlight');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        $('span:contains("'+$(this).attr('title')+'")').removeClass('highlight');
    }
);
```

**Edit:** This is what it will look like on your page. http://jsfiddle.net/6BH27/1/

Comment: looks nice, Danke! I'll implement and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help in correcting my mistake!

Comment: how would I go about implementing this as a wordpress shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Here is also another thing that may help. It highlights each text when hovered over. You can edit the jquery part to suite what you need.

```
<style>
        #english {
        display:inline-block;
        }
        #tibetan {
        display:inline-block;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#english").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#tibetan").css("background-color", "yellow")
            $("#english").css("background-color", "yellow")
        })
        $("#tibetan").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#tibetan").css("background-color", "yellow")
            $("#english").css("background-color", "yellow")
        })
        $("#english").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#tibetan").css("background-color", "transparent")
            $("#english").css("background-color", "transparent")
        })
        $("#tibetan").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#tibetan").css("background-color", "transparent")
            $("#english").css("background-color", "transparent")
        })
    });
    </script>
    <p id="tibetan" title="&#3914;&#3954;&#3926;&#3962;&#3919;&#3923;&#3851;">&#3914;&#3954;&#3926;&#3962;&#3919;&#3923;&#3851;</p><br />
    <p id="english" title="English">English</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help in correcting my mistake!